# MPMoviePlayerController's initial and end time properties...destructive?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

If I set up a MPMovieController and change the initial and end times on a video using

```
[moviePlayerController setEndPlaybackTime:3.7];
```

is the movie shortened destructively?  If I later want to play a different part of the movie outside the new bounds, am I stuck?  I am basically creating an interactive animation using different sections of a video.

Thanks,

-R

Comment: I ended up using AVFoundation to write a custom player.  This solved my problem.

Comment: I found the solution in the below think.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768972/mpmovieplayercontroller-how-to-play-part-of-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`endPlaybackTime` is not manipulating the actual movie content, hence it is not destructive.